# Is there anyway I can improve Logstash performance when it shows high CPU usage?

Tags: cpu, performance

I am new to ELK and I am running ELK in a CentOS 7 environment. I have 4 CPU cores in this machine and with the default configuration of Logstash, the CPU usage is always very high.

[image: Process list]

Knowing that running Logstash is I/O intensive and multiline consumes a lot of CPU resource, here below is my Logstash configuration file. May I know how to optimize the CPU utilization for Logstash performance?

```
input {
file {
path => ["java.log"]
start_position => "beginning"
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
codec => multiline {
patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/custom-patterns/custom"
pattern => "^%{NUMBER20} "
negate => true
what => previous
}
type => "xservice"
}
}

filter {
if [type] == "xservice" {
mutate {
replace => {document_type => "xservice"}
gsub => ["message", "\n", ""]
}

grok {
patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/custom-patterns/custom"
match => {"message" => "%{JAVALOG}"}
}

date {
match => ["timestamp","YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
target => "@timestamp"
remove_field => ["timestamp"]
}
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
index => "%{document_type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
}
```

The CPU usage is very high even I have the Logstash configuration in default settings.

Comment: The first question about this is: Is this really an issue over the long haul? Is this a server install of Logstash or a local install? Your CPU usage shows 345% usage so there has to be at least 4 CPU cores on your setup. In my experience when you first start Logstash, CPU usage blows up… But then after a while it all settles down.

Comment: It is a server installed with ELK and yes there are 4 CPU cores assigned to this server. I have been running it for the past 15 minutes and the CPU consumed during this process is within a range between 85 - 100%. Is this a normal bahaviour?

Comment: So can you clarify: The screenshot shows 345% usage but you say 85% to 100% usage? So usage was lowered over time? Or is that 85% to 100% for your system as a whole?

Comment: yes as a whole. monitoring the whole system itself here.

Comment: Honestly, that’s par for the course as far as I know. I use Logstash without a full Elk stack and it’s resource intensive. With a full Elk stack? I can only imagine it being more of the same; it’s not an efficient application.